# Vue.js can't write anything in form inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'll be straight to the point, in all my project I can't write in `<input>` or `<v-text-field>`.

I chose Vue 2 and vuetify 2.6 for doing my front-end app.

I have no ideia why it is not possible to interect or type in any inputs in all project,look like is every input is "disabled", even It isn't.

So here we go, I'll share some codes, I hope you can help me:

```
<template>
    <section class="main-container">
        <div class="newsletter-card">

            <h2>Confira as novidades através de nossa newsletter.</h2>
            <p class="body-large">Fique de olho, os primeiros assinantes participarão
                de sorteios exclusivos.</p>

            <div class="div-form">
                <v-form v-model="valid">
                    <v-text-field v-model="form.email" solo label="Solo" clearable></v-text-field>
                </v-form>
            </div>
            <p class="small-paragraph">*ao submeter o seu endereço de e-mail, você está confirmando que aceita se
                inscrever
                em nossa newsletter.</p>
            <img class="img-spine"
                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dpwcbwkzl/image/upload/v1666993740/development/line-vector-desk_1_l8ofkk.png"
                alt="">
        </div>
    </section>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "NewsletterComponent",
    data: function () {
        return {
            valid: false,
            form: {
                email: "",
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[image: Component with an input not working]

Since I don't know if the problem is at the component itself or vuejs in a configuration. I'll share my `package.json` and `main.js`, maybe is happening a dependency conflit.

```
{
  "name": "omnilaw-front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.8.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@volar-plugins/vetur": "latest",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What about the Vue devtools? Is the state properly set there? What is `valid` used for here? Can you display some state in your template? Got a public github repo?

Comment: @kissu there isnt any error on the console. I'm considering start a new vue cli project and copy the files to this new project I hope is some silly error when I created using vue cli. This repository is private I cant share because Im working on a startup and of course this is private information ) =

Comment: Yep, please try to reproduce it into a public repo so that we can look into it!

Comment: @AdrielKirch I tested your codes. It works fine for me. Maybe the problem is from your styles, also I think ```valid: false``` or ```valid: true``` is for form validation. If you don't do that, remove that data.

Answer (score 0):

I made a minimal [reproduciton sandbox](https://codepen.io/rustamd/pen/NWzqoOY), and it works as expected. The only thing that is missing are your CSS class definitions, which I think is your problem in this case.

You probably have `pointer-events: none` in one of your classes.

If you would like to keep classes as is, you can add inline style to your form or enclosing `<div>` like so: `style="pointer-events: all"`

If this does not fix it, and you are still not getting any errors in dev tools console, I would then inspect the element to see what classes/styles are applied to it, and report back.

Comment: Brother, thanks a lot with your code I noticed that the issue wasn't in the vuetify configuration. But after remove that "spine img art" image the problem has just been fixed